# How to check all the numbers in a range against a calculation?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to print all the prime numbers up to 100. Here's my code so far:

```
primes = []

for num in range(100):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i != 0:
                primes += [num]
                break
            else:
                break
            
print(primes)
```

However when i run the code, it only does the calculation (`if num % i != 0`) for the first iteration in the range (`for i in range(2, num)`). This is a problem in the case of numbers like 15, where the first iteration in `for i in range` is 2. 15 divided by 2 does not give a whole number, and so it runs `primes += [num]`. It has taken the first iteration and has not run the rest of them. Is there a way to run all the iterations in the range?

Comment: Just remove the break in `if num % i != 0:`, you need to check that the number isn't divisible for all the numbers in the range (you could to up to sqrt(num) though), otherwise the logic of the program is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
primes = []

for num in range(100):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(num)

print(primes)
```

The code will execute the `else` block only if the inner `for` loop is exhausted, i.e completes it's all iteration without breaking.

Answer (score 1):

You got the logic somewhat wrong. Here's how you've to do it

```
primes = []

for num in range(2, 100): # 0 and 1 aren't primes
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            break
    else: # the else condition is for the for loop i.e. if it executes without break
        primes.append(num)
            
print(primes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [all](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#all) function may be what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it.

```py
>>> def primes(limit=100):
...     for number in range(limit):
...         is_prime = all([number % divisor != 0 for divisor in range(2, number)])
...         if is_prime:
...             yield number
...
>>> list(primes(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
>>> list(primes(100))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
>>>
```

Is not complete, 0 and 1 are not primes. But I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

tried to adapt to your approach although, I think there should be better ways to solve this problem

```
>>> primes = []
>>> for num in range(2,100):
...     p = True
...     for i in range(2, num):
...         if num % i == 0:
...             p = False
...     if p:
...         primes += [num]
...
>>> primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```